# android: how to change Text size, color of Options Menu Items and options menu height and width

Tags: android, options-menu

I have used the following code to customize the background of options menu successfully.

```
getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
            try { // Ask our inflater to create the view
                LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                /*
                 * The background gets refreshed each time a new item is
                 * added the options menu. So each time Android applies
                 * the default background we need to set our own
                 * background. This is done using a thread giving the
                 * background change as runnable object
                 */
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_bg_pixel);
                    }
                });
                return view;
            }
            catch (InflateException e) {
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Now I have to customize menu size, text size/color. Anybody plz help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see the answer: 

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223846/android-adding-text-color-background-and-font-size-to-optionsmenu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's obsolete. Options menu was triggered by hardware menu key on platforms older than Android 4. Contemporary equivalent would be ActionBar popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

This fails on Android 2.3

See
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4441#c6
and
[Change menu background color on android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614158/change-menu-background-color-on-android-2-3)

for details

Answer (score 0):

Width , Heigth you need hack action bar to that.

But if you need customize, use : ActionBarGenerator (http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)